# Как инициализировать множество multi-select с одним и тем же классом? (slim-select jquery plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Насколько я понял с небольшого "гайда" на сайте плагина для инициализации используется:

```
new SlimSelect({
    select: 'здесь идентификатор элемента'
})
```

Но задавать это 10 раз для 10 multi-select и при этом использовать разные классы немного неправильно на мой взгляд поэтому вопрос заключается в следующем: Можно как-то сделать это за 1 заход для 10 multi-select с одинаковыми классами?

Answer (score 0):

```
allSelects = document.querySelectorAll("select")
allSelects.forEach(function (el) {
  new SlimSelect({
    select: el
  })
})
```

Comment: Это сработает только для одного элемента но не для 10

Comment: Подправил ответ. Если на странице есть и другие селекты, которые не нужно никак оформлять, просто перечислите идентификаторы нужных в массиве: allSelects = ['#element1', '#element2']